# Max number of promoted units on the board in a monochromatic game

Tags: chess-variants, pawn-promotion, retrograde-analysis, monochromatic

A whimsical question just occurred to me. I think I have an answer, but I thought I would share it here as a puzzle.

What is the maximum number of promoted units that can appear simultaneously on the board in a monochromatic game?

(with reference to [What are "monochromatic" retrograde analysis problems?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/43400/what-are-monochromatic-retrograde-analysis-problems))

Please find a game to illustrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes four captures to promote a pawn in monochromatic. Only 15/16 of each sides' pieces are capturable. Thus, in theory, each side may only promote three pawns at most, or a total maximum of six combined.

And it is indeed possible, albeit tricky. Utilizing en passant to change a pawn's lane color is a crucial aspect.

```
[FEN ""]

1. a4 a5 2. b4 b5 3. bxa5 bxa4 4. g4 g5 5. h4 h5 6. Rh3 Rh6 7. Rb3 Rb6 8. axb6 axb3 9. bxc7 bxc2 10. cxb8=N Qb6 11. d4 Qc5 12. dxc5 d5 13. cxd6 Bf5 14. Bf4 Bh7 15. Bh2 gxh4 16. gxh5 Ra6 17. Ra3 cxb1=N 18. dxe7 Rg6 19. Rg3 hxg3 20. hxg6 gxh2 21. gxh7 f5 22. e4 fxe4 23. f4 exf3 24. Be2 fxe2 25. exf8=B hxg1=N 26. hxg8=N exd1=Q
```

Comment: I hoped this would appeal to you Rewan :)

Comment: This is long known to "monochromators", though :-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I wouldn't be surprised but do you have a reference?

Comment: @Laska: Sorry, no. That I "know" something just means I'm a know-it-all, and often "needs citation". :-) You have to ask an actual expert.

Comment: Oh @HaukeReddmann you "guess-it-all". I agree it’s an obvious idea, but I have searched in PDB, and there appears to be nothing that addresses this task in the 342 mono problems with solutions nor the 104 without solutions. I am speaking with Thierry Le Gleuher about sth else, and may I ask him

Answer (score 1):

I want to complement @RewanDemontay's accepted answer.

It's clear that the number of promotions can't be more than 6, because each promotion involves 4 captures, plus the promoted unit itself which is not eligible for captures. (32-2)/(4+1) = 30/5 = 6.

One can divide the pieces into 4 sets of 8. How many promoted pawns can share the same square colour as their king? There are several patterns possible from simple counting, but only two can work out:

**Case 1**

|  | White dark sq | White light sq | Black light sq | Black dark sq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| King | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Promoted pawns | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Captured units | 6 | 4 | 6 | 4 |
| Captured e.p. | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| Total | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |

**Case 2**

From counting we get:

|  | White dark sq | White light sq | Black light sq | Black dark sq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| King | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Promoted pawns | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Captured units | 3 or 4 | 6 or 7 | 3 or 4 | 6 or 7 |
| Captured e.p. | 2 or 1 | 1 or 0 | 2 or 1 | 1 or 0 |
| Total | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |

Now looking a little deeper, the White promotion on light squares must capture PBNR or eBNR (where e means en passant pawn). The latter is not possible, since e, N & R must all be captured on 6th or 8th rank. Similarly for the Black dark square promotion. So the only possibility is:

|  | White dark sq | White light sq | Black light sq | Black dark sq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| King | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Promoted pawns | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Captured units | 4 | 7 | 4 | 7 |
| Captured e.p. | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Total | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |

**Case 3** (not possible)

|  | White dark sq | White light sq | Black light sq | Black dark sq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| King | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Promoted pawns | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Captured units | 5 | 4 | 4 | 6 |
| Captured e.p. | 0 | **3?!?** | 2 | 0 |
| Total | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |

This "asymmetric pattern" (and its mirror image) are not possible, because it requires too many en passant. Each promoting pawn can capture e.p. at most once.